# Magento Programming: Importing manufacturers while checking for existing duplicates and get manu. ID

Tags: php, magento, import

I need some help doing the following.

I am trying to import a list of manufacturers with pre-verification from the targeted store that new manufacturer to be imported does not already exist (if new manufacturer name already exist, skip) and get its new manufacturer ID if imported.

I have the code to just add manufacturer w/o checking for existing manufacturer by name nor getting the new manufacturer ID.  The code is here, but I need the abilities thats stated above.

Any help would be great. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
umask(0);
Mage::app('default');
$_manufacturers = file('manufacturers.txt');
$_attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');
$manufacturers = array('value' => array(), 'order' => array(), 'delete' => array());
$i = 0;
foreach($_manufacturers as $_manufacturer){
$i++;
$manufacturers['value']['option_' . $i] = array($_manufacturer);
}
$_attribute->setOption($manufacturers);
try{
$_attribute->save();
echo 'Manufacturer successfully imported';
}catch(Exception $e){
echo 'Import Error::'.$e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Comment: -1 http://www.emilvikstrom.se/whyidownvote.html (What have you tried?)

Comment: I have looked on the interenet and found nothing to help.  All I need is to pre-check if a manufacturer to be added already exist and if not, add it and get its new ID.  I've tried using the code above.

Comment: So you have not tried writing any code at all?

Comment: I can't find anything that would help.  I made some mods to the above code and nothing seems to work.  If u are just asking me ques. and not help please just help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a quick and dirty script, but this should be what you are looking for...

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);    
ini_set('display_errors', 1); 


/*
 * Boostrap Magento
 */
$mageFilename = '../app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;        
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);     
umask(0);

$mageRunCode = '';
$mageRunType = 'store';
Mage::init($mageRunCode, $mageRunType);

/*
 * Set up required data
 */
$newManufacturers = file('manufacturers.txt', FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES | FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$newManufacturers = array_unique($newManufacturers);

$attribute = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')
                ->loadByCode('catalog_product', 'manufacturer');

$valuesCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
            ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getData('attribute_id'))
            ->setStoreFilter(0, false)
            ->getColumnValues('value');

$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup'); 

/*
 * Add new attributes
 */
$addedManufacturers      = array();
$skippedManufacturers    = array();

$i = count($valuesCollection);
foreach($newManufacturers as $manufacturer) {

    // If the value already exists then skip to next  
    if (in_array($manufacturer, $valuesCollection)) {
        $skippedManufacturers[] = $manufacturer;
        continue;
    }

    //If we have reached here then lets add the new attribute option
    $newOption = array();
    $newOption['attribute_id'] = $attribute->getData('attribute_id');
    $newOption['value']['option_'.++$i][0] = $manufacturer;
    $installer->addAttributeOption($newOption);

    $optionValue = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_option_collection')
            ->setAttributeFilter($attribute->getId())
            ->setStoreFilter(0, false)
            ->addFilter('value_id', $installer->getConnection()->lastInsertId())   
            ->getColumnValues('option_id');

    $addedManufacturers[] = $optionValue[0];
}

if (count($addedManufacturers)) {
    echo "<h2>Manufacturers Added</h2><ul>";
    foreach($addedManufacturers as $added) {
        echo "<li>" . $added . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}

if (count($skippedManufacturers)) {
    echo "<h2>Manufacturers Skipped</h2><ul>";
    foreach($skippedManufacturers as $skipped) {
        echo "<li>" . $skipped . "</li>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
}
```

Comment: thank you, however, I also need to get the newly added unique manufacturer's magento ID after its been added.  Is that possible?

Comment: Thank you again, one final thing that seems to dumbfound me is this... Is it possible to get a list of all manufacturers name with their corresponding magento ID?  I tried some mods but only get one or the other.  If its possible, pls help w/ this one last thing.  I thank you in advance Drew :)

Comment: Hi - that's really a different question to this. If you create a new question for that I'll gladly provide an answer for you. Cheers, Drew

Comment: Hi, I asked a new question concerning that.  Its Here. I thank you again...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10887987/magento-programming-getting-list-of-all-manufacturers-and-corresponding-manufac

Comment: @user1433709 - You will find it easier to get people to help you on Stack Overflow if you accept answers if you feel they are correct :)

Comment: May I ask where is the best site for magento tutorial and ref?